# AMD CCC and best 3D performace

Tags: graphics-card, performance-tuning

Which settings in the AMD Vision Engine Control Center does **heavily** affect 3D rendering performance?

This is what i have in the "Gaming->3D Application Settings" section:
[image: 3D Application Settings shot]

I'm aiming to alter only the settings that could give a significative performace boost (~10fps).

Comment: Probably a gamer site will give better answers...

Comment: Such as [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/), you may get the best responses there.

Comment: Flag for this question to be migrated instead of posting a duplicate on any other SE site (such as Arqade). If it can't be migrated for some reason (as might be the case if the destination is in beta), most likely a mod will inform you via a comment so that you can then re-post there if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, your graphic card uses resources that are demanded from app you are using.

But in AMD CCC you can force some lower settings that can affect your experience and FPS rate.

I use to reduce/turn off antialiasing and shadows as I've found that most resource demanding. You can try each setting and see what effect you get.